# How do I prevent Light2D node from changing color of a sprite in Godot?

Tags: shader, game-engine, godot

I am making an Among Us clone with multiplayer, and I'm a little stuck at recreating the lighting effect around the players. Heres what I have right now: [image: a video of the game]

I'm getting this weird whitish color on the slave players on each client. These are my options for the CanvasShader on each player's AnimatedSprite Node, it shows Light mode as normal but I change it to "light only" during runtime for slave players so that the master player(the player each client controls) doesn't get affected by the light.

[image: my player canvas settings]

Why does this happen and how can I fix this?

Edit:
All my project files and code are available here if anyone would like to see something else https://github.com/MysteryCoder456/AmongUsRemake

Answer (score -1):

I made a copy of your game and I change you light image along with other setting like the size of the mask since the mask must cover the entire screen to work.

Here it the link to my fixed version: https://github.com/qas-source/Amoung-us-remake-fix, all credits to you for this game so far though.

You main problem was the sharp end to you light texture and other light settings like size and strength. When It comes to light2D, mess with the settings until you get it just right.